# How do I render different shapes on each row of a SAPUI5 Gantt chart?

Tags: sapui5, gantt-chart

In my application, I have to render Projects, Tasks and Milestones. Projects and Tasks are differently coloured bars, and the Milestone is a Diamond (I'm using `BaseRectangle` and `BaseDiamond` respectively).

Since some items in my hierarchy are Projects, Some Tasks and Some Milestones, how can I render differing shapes on each row?

My first thought was to use the common "visible" property, but shapes don't have that, conversely "opacity" makes things invisible, but they still respond to mouse position.

I then tried using an Aggregation factory function, but although my chart renders correctly on first display, it doesn't recalculate the shapes on expanding or collapsing branches.

It seems to me that the factory function *should* work, but something is breaking in the chart that doesn't throw errors to console.

At the moment in my XML template, I have the following:

- `rowSettingTemplate` has `shapes1={path: factory:}` and no `shapes1` element.
- Each of my `BaseShapes` is in a different fragment which are attached to my `TreeTable` as dependents.

Example Shape Fragment - Project.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:gnt2="sap.gantt.simple">

    <gnt2:BaseRectangle id="shapeProject"
        shapeId="{plandata>id}" countInBirdEye="true"
        time="{plandata>start_date}" endTime="{plandata>end_date}"
        resizable="true" selectable="true" draggable= "true" connectable="true"
        title="{plandata>text}" showTitle="true"
        tooltip=""
        fill="#0c1" />

</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Factory function:

```
    shapeFactory: function(sId, oContext) {
        var parentId = (/(.*)-\d+$/.exec(sId))[1];
        var rowSettings = sap.ui.getCore().byId(parentId);

        var node: Project.Node = oContext.getProperty();

        if (String(node.id) == rowSettings.getProperty("rowId")) {
            switch (node.type) {
                case "project":
                    return this.byId('shapeProject').clone(sId);
                case "task":
                    return this.byId('shapeTask').clone(sId);
                case "milestone":
                    return this.byId('shapeMilestone').clone(sId);
                default:
                    return this.byId('shapeErr').clone(sId);
            }
        } else {
            return this.byId('shapeEmpty').clone(sId);
        }
    }
```

My empty shape is a `BaseGroup` - note that SAPUI5 crashes if I return a `null` from factory, so something has to be returned when I actually want nothing.

I also tried wrapping all my shapes in `BaseGroup` so that the chart always sees the same control type, but that doesn't work. Note also that if I return a clone of `Empty` each time without any special logic, then the chart works correctly.

I'm hoping that this is a settings or something to ensure that the aggregation works properly each time. My SAPUI5 version is 1.61.2 — I'll try 1.63.1 when I get some time, but I think that this issue is fairly deep down.

If anybody has any ideas or sample code, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.gantt.sample.BasicGanttChart/preview shows a method of varying shapes based on name of sub-objects in the data. How would I use this mechanism if my row data object has a type field instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a workaround for this, that may save somebody several hours. Basically instead of defining the shapes1 aggregation via a factory function, I have used the `<shapes1>` tag instead. My Shapes1 tag contains a reference to my own custom shape which derives from BaseRectangle. My custom shape can then render whatever SVG it requires based on the bound object context. Now my tree can expand and collapse whilst rendering whatever shapes are required.

My renderer now looks like this:

```
CustomChartShape.prototype.renderElementRectangle = BaseRectangle.prototype.renderElement;
CustomChartShape.prototype.renderElementDiamond = BaseDiamond.prototype.renderElement;

CustomChartShape.prototype.renderElement = function(oRm, oElement) {
    // There is possibilities that x is invalid number.
    // for instance wrong timestamp binded to time property
    if (this.bHasInvalidPropValue) { return; }

    var Node = this.getBindingInfo('endTime').binding.getContext().getProperty();

    if (Node.type == "milestone") {
        this.renderElementDiamond(oRm, oElement);
    } else {
        this.renderElementRectangle(oRm, oElement);
    }
}
```

I had to provide a 'getD' function that has a fixed width, and I'll have o go through and rewrite several functions, but I think that this will work for me.